# Error: Cannot find module '../types/array/isMongooseArray' in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose, npm-install

The project is wroking fine on **heroku locally when I run on Heroku CLI**. But when I open the app  from Heroku portal.
It's not running and logs file says this:- It can't find some 'isMongooseArray' module.

```
ent projects\nav demo>heroku logs --tail --app mineportfoliowebsite
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096383+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/internal.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096384+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096384+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096384+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096384+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096386+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096387+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096387+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/isMongooseObject.js:3:25)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096388+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096389+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096389+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096389+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096390+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/isMongooseObject.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096390+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/clone.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096390+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/options/PopulateOptions.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096390+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096390+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/internal.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js',
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096391+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/app.js'
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096392+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2022-02-11T19:03:25.096392+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2022-02-11T19:03:25.100470+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
2022-02-11T19:04:23.402776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-02-11T19:04:23.540569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-02-11T19:04:23.757390+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-02-11T19:04:23.841315+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-02-11T19:04:23.918195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-11T19:04:26.098052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-02-11T19:04:27.443629+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-11T19:04:27.443663+00:00 app[web.1]: > nav-demo@1.0.0 start
2022-02-11T19:04:27.443663+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon app.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.443663+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-11T19:04:27.608951+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] 2.0.15
2022-02-11T19:04:27.609690+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
2022-02-11T19:04:27.609988+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
2022-02-11T19:04:27.610009+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
2022-02-11T19:04:27.610303+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
2022-02-11T19:04:27.760868+00:00 app[web.1]: hi-0
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892679+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892681+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892682+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892682+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892683+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../types/array/isMongooseArray'
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892683+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892684+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/isMongooseObject.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892684+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/clone.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892684+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/options/PopulateOptions.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892685+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892685+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/statemachine.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892685+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/internal.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892686+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892686+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892686+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2022-02-11T19:04:27.892686+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
```

This is my app.js file:-

```
const express = require('express');
console.log('hi-0');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('nodemon');
```

Everything works fine and 'hi-0' is also seen. But at the line of mongoose, is starts creating problem.

I wanted to ask how to install Mongoose module locally on node.js so that it works fine when deploying on 'Heroku'. Because Express module is working absolutely fine.

This is my package.json file:-

```
{
  "name": "nav-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.13.x",
    "npm": "8.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/1Priyanka-Sharma/portfolio-second.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/1Priyanka-Sharma/portfolio-second/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/1Priyanka-Sharma/portfolio-second#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.19",
    "vite": "^2.7.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "hbs": "^4.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

When I comment  let mongoose = require('mongoose'); this line. Everything works well on Heroku. But when I uncomment it, it shows error.

**One more thing, when I hover over 'express' word on my app.js, its shows this:-'module "C:/Users/Deepti Sharma/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/4.5/node_modules/@types/express/index"'.
But when I hover over 'mongoose' module, its shows only this:-'module "mongoose"'.**

Please help.

Comment: Side note: `nodemon` is only for development. Don't use it on Heroku.

Comment: I suspect you aren't running a production build. Please show your `package.json` and, if you have one, your `Procfile`.

Comment: no, I don't have Procfile file.